# Can I get the count of string array, where it equals to a word?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

```
 String[] sprüche = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wörter);
 String[] textl=text.split(" ");       
 for (int kl=0;kl<textl.length;kl++){
            if (Arrays.asList(sprüche).contains(textl[kl])){


            }
        }
```

Thats my code. I want to know at which point "sprüche" contains "textl[kl]".
What I have to do?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Hint: `List.indexOf` is almost certainly what you're looking for here. Note that you only need to call `Arrays.asList` once - you can use that list throughout the loop...

Comment: You have to explain why you are having difficulty in doing so, at least if you want an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm you said can I get the count in your question title and in the post you said a which point the word occurs in the array... Hmmm

Try those code :

```
public int sprücheContains(String []sprüche, String Textl )
{
    int k = sprüche.lenght();
    int count = 0;
    for (int k1 = 0; k1 < k; k1++){

         if (sprüche[k1].equals(textl) {
             count++;
         }
    }
    return count;   

}
```

It will return the number of times `textl` appears in `sprüche`

---

```
public List<Integer> sprücheContains(String []sprüche, String Textl )
{
    int k = sprüche.lenght();

    List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int k1 = 0; k1 < k; k1++){

         if (sprüche[k1].equals(textl) {
             positions.add(k1)
         }
    }
    return positions;   

}
```

This will return all the indexes position of occurences of `Textl` in `sprüche`